# Can RoboBrowser open a html string?

Tags: python, html, robobrowser

I would like to benefit from the awesome features of the `RoboBrowser` on a HTML string that contains some forms.

Usually `Robobrowser` is used like that:

```py
url = "whatever.com"
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open(url)
thatForm = browser.get_form("thatForm")
thatForm["thisField"].value = "some value"
browser.submit(thatForm)
```

I would like to use the html content of string to do the same, I was expecting something like below to work:

```py
content = "<html>...</html>"
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open(content)
```

However, this does not, cause the `open` method expects that the string is a url not a html content, is there anything that can be done, any workaround so that I can pass a html content string somewhere and `RoboBrowser` parses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I found a solution, not super elegant but it works, basically it all revolves around the `_update_state` function which is actually called at some point internally by Robobrowser when opening a URL:

```py
def open(self, url, method='get', **kwargs):
    """Open a URL.

    :param str url: URL to open
    :param str method: Optional method; defaults to `'get'`
    :param kwargs: Keyword arguments to `Session::request`

    """
    response = self.session.request(method, url, **self._build_send_args(**kwargs))
    self._update_state(response)
```

The solution is therefore to simply create a fake response carrying the html we want to be parsed:

```
fake_response = requests.Response()
fake_response._content = the_html_we_want_Robobrowser_to_parse
browser = RoboBrowser()
browser._update_state(fake_response)
my_form = browser.get_form("myform")
browser.submit_form(my_form)
```

And voila :)